# How to exclude unwanted items from Azure Diagnostics Trace

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I have setup Azure Diagnostics and using Trace to log any messages.
The problem is that when I go to the Azure WADLogsTable, I see that in addition to my messages there is a lot of crap that I want to eliminate.

How do I remove mesages like these?

```
IDependencyResolver.GetService<ASP._Page_Views_Account_Login_cshtml>() = ASP._Page_Views_Account_Login_cshtml
IDependencyResolver.GetService<System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadataProvider>() = null
```

The only thing that I want to show are the things that I put there like this:

```
Trace.WriteLine("This is not good", "Information");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your web.config does not contain any Trace config statements that send system messages to trace.